# How to include an auto generated file in a MsBuild project?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, sqlmetal, dblinq

Using MsBuild 4.0 I included a pre-build event that generates one of the project source files.
But it seeks for the file before it is generated:

> error CS1504: Source file 'c:\src\Data\Main.Designer.cs' could not be opened ('Unspecified error ')

The file is generated by DbMetal/SqlMetal.
Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your action to BeforeBuild target. In the project *.csproj it is by default commented.
Uncomment it and call DBMetal using [Exec task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx)

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="<your prebuild action 1>"/>
    <Exec Command="<your prebuild action 2>"/>
</Target>
```

If you are working with **Datasource.db** and want to generate **Main.Designer.cs**
you can specify [Input and Output parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t50z2hka.aspx) for the target. It will saves you calling DBMetal and rebuilding the project itself.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild"
        Inputs="Datasource.db"
        Outputs="Main.Designer.cs">
    <Exec Command="<your prebuild action 1>"/>
    <Exec Command="<your prebuild action 2>"/>
</Target>
```